# PyTorch MaxPool2D unexpected behavior with padding=1

Tags: python, pytorch, max-pooling

I was playing around with `MaxPool2D` in `PyTorch` and discovered strange behavior when setting `padding=1`. Here is what I got:

**Code:**

```py
import torch
from torch.nn.functional import max_pool2d

TEST = 1


def test_maxpool(negative=False, tnsr_size=2, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0):
    """Test MaxPool2D.
    """
    global TEST
    print(f'=== TEST {TEST} ===')
    print(*[f'{i[0]}: {i[1]}' for i in locals().items()], sep=' | ')

    inp = torch.arange(1., tnsr_size ** 2 + 1).reshape(1, tnsr_size, tnsr_size)
    inp = -inp if negative else inp

    print('In:')
    print(inp)

    out = max_pool2d(inp, kernel_size, stride, padding=padding)
    print('Out:')
    print(out)
    print()
    TEST += 1


test_maxpool()
test_maxpool(True)

test_maxpool(padding=1)
test_maxpool(True, padding=1)
```

**Out:**

```py
=== TEST 1 ===
negative: False | tnsr_size: 2 | kernel_size: 2 | stride: 2 | padding: 0
In:
tensor([[[1., 2.],
         [3., 4.]]])
Out:
tensor([[[4.]]])

=== TEST 2 ===
negative: True | tnsr_size: 2 | kernel_size: 2 | stride: 2 | padding: 0
In:
tensor([[[-1., -2.],
         [-3., -4.]]])
Out:
tensor([[[-1.]]])

=== TEST 3 ===
negative: False | tnsr_size: 2 | kernel_size: 2 | stride: 2 | padding: 1
In:
tensor([[[1., 2.],
         [3., 4.]]])
Out:
tensor([[[1., 2.],
         [3., 4.]]])

=== TEST 4 ===
negative: True | tnsr_size: 2 | kernel_size: 2 | stride: 2 | padding: 1
In:
tensor([[[-1., -2.],
         [-3., -4.]]])
Out:
tensor([[[-1., -2.],
         [-3., -4.]]])
```

*Tests 1, 2, 3* are fine but *Test 4* is weird, I expected to get `[[0 0], [0 0]]` tensor:

```py
In:
[[-1 -2]
 [-3 -4]]

+ padding -> 

[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 -1 -2  0]
 [ 0 -3 -4  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0]]

-> kernel_size=2, stride=2 ->

[[0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

According to *Test 3* zero padding was used but *Test 4* produced controversial result.

What kind of padding (if any) was that? Why does `MaxPool2D` behave like that?

`pytorch 1.3.1`

Comment: I agree with you and [posted this as a bug on the pytorch issue tracker](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/33384)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was expected behavior since negative infinity padding is done by default.

The documentation for MaxPool is now fixed. See this PR: [Fix MaxPool default pad documentation #59404](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/59404) .

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is still incorrect in the `Parameters` section, where it says:

> **padding** – implicit zero padding to be added on both sides